# Size of a string type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I know that `ObjectIDs` are 12-bytes in MongoDB. And I know that `numbers` are 64-bit. But how do I find out the size of a saved `string`

Comment: db.test.findOne().string_fielsd.length;

Comment: @Disposer: the OP is asking for the *size* of the string, not the *length*. Many string implementations also store the string's length and might or might not add a null terminator. Moreover, while length and size of the string *itself* are the same thing in ASCII, they certainly aren't in UTF-8, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. For instance, "ä" has `length` 1, but requires two bytes to store (`0xC3A4`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bson specification at http://bsonspec.org/spec.html is a good starting point.

In particular, it's important to realize that BSON *does* have integer types, including 32 bit integers which is even the default, despite the fact that JavaScript uses a 64 bit floating point numbers - MongoDB uses JavaScript a lot, but it's not *written* in JavaScript and has different types. The existence of true integers is quite important, otherwise a `$inc` on a large number wouldn't work.

To answer your question: strings are stored as UTF-8 encoded strings with a zero terminator and a 32-bit length in front, plus the 1-byte type indicator and the element name, of course. Keep in mind that objects have additional overhead.

Comment: _-"Keep in mind that objects have additional overhead."_ ... Not sure I understand you here. Could you elaborate this =)

Comment: As you can see in the BSON spec, the document itself is composed of the total length in bytes, an `e_list` and a zero terminator. The `e_list` is a list of elements, each of which has an element which has a type indicator, the element name and the actual data. An embedded document will be an element of its own, so nesting will increase the size (naturally). Moreover, documents will be padded not only by the padding factor, but also such that its size in bytes is a multiple of 16 (might depend on version and OS).