# Is it necessary to store document references as type ObjectId in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

Reading the mongo docs for modeling many-to-many relationships, I see they are using simple strings for the `_id`

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

where I imagined it was beneficial to use actual `ObjectId` values as per this question: [Difference between storing an ObjectId and its string form, in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896979/difference-between-storing-an-objectid-and-its-string-form-in-mongodb)

I’m finding it complex to have to cast between the object and string as this data passes back and forth between the Frontend (Vue) and backend (NestJS/Node) as JSON and am wondering if there is any real necessity to concern myself with utilizing `ObjectId` as it adds a fair bit of complexity.

**Does storing the reference id as a string make any difference when performing an aggregation/$graphLookup? Am I meant to actually store this reference itself as an ObjectId or is that wholly unnecessary?**

Comment: The answer to the question you referenced already answers your question.

Comment: I’m not sure if it matters but I believe the other question speaks to the _id itself. I was wondering if there is any need to store the reference as ObjectId as well or is it basically a blanket rule that every ObjectId should always be stored as such and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirement for the values of `_id` is that they be unique as the `_id` is always indexed automatically by MongoDB and that index is unique.

The purpose of ObjectIDs is to allow the client to generate an ID that is guaranteed to be unique across a broad range of clients that are writing to the same collection. If you have a better unique ID you are encouraged to use it as it saves you an index. You do **not** need to cast that value into an ObjectID. It can be used in the clear as can other types (e.g. integers Decimals etc.).