# Why I could still assign ObjectId type value to an Array of String in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, types

I'm using node with typescript, and mongoose for database.

I have this code that takes user model from database (using mongoose) by user id, then takes the user roles attribute. The roles attribute contains array of object. Inside each object (roles) contains _id

```
// Check User Roles
      const user = await this.userModel.findById(req.identitas.user._id)
      const userRoles: Array<string> = []
      for (let index in user.roles) {
        userRoles.push((user.roles[index]._id))
      }
```

When i try to check the type of what's pushed to userRoles

```
console.log(typeof(userRoles[0]))
```

It says that it has `object` type variable.

I then decided to try

```
userRoles.push({ dummy: "dummy" })
```

and it wouldn't let me do that. So I know for sure that the type declaration in

```
const userRoles: Array<sring> = []
```

is working properly. But, at the same time, it isn't. When I try to push _id to userRoles, it still somehow allows me to do that.

This is a problem because I'm using this userRoles array of string to compare it with another string value, using

```
userRoles.includes("some-string-here")
```

Why and how did this thing could happen?

*This is what `user` variable contains:

```
{
  roles: [
    {
      _id: 5f93fdc**********36,
      name: 'Karyawan Cabang Neutron',
      ...
      __v: 2,
      policies: [],
      organization: 5f8fe9a62*****000082e3fef
    }
  ],
  units: [
    {
      _id: 5fc1f9******00081b2897,
      name: 'Neutron Yogyakarta 2',
      code: '102',
      organization: 5f8fe****42a2000kj13fef,
      createdAt: 2020-11-28T07:18:09.628Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-11-28T07:18:09.628Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  organizations: [
    {
      _id: 5f8c6b*****b75jg008d4a156,
      ...
      __v: 34,
      code: 'NEO',
      logo: [Object],
      content: [Array],
      object: [Object],
      config: [Array]
    }
  ],
  _id: 5fdad1a25e9f78****c42,
  email: 'email@example.com',
  username: 'EmiliaBestGirl',
  ...
  isEmailVerified: true,
  identities: [],
  createdAt: 2020-12-17T03:33:54.484Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-12-22T08:12:24.019Z,
  __v: 3,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE it's hard to tell what could be going on.  What's the type of `user.roles`?

Comment: @jcalz In console.log(typeof(user.roles)) it gave me `object` type. Maybe I'll edit the question and add what `user` is containing

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896979/difference-between-storing-an-objectid-and-its-string-form-in-mongodb) regarding the ObjectID in MongoDB. From what I read there, string and ObjectId is different from each other.. So this Array<string> should not contain any other type than string